# Regular Expression - remove quotes from HTML attributes that does not contain spaces but keep quotes around URLs

Tags: magento2, regex

I'm trying to simplify HTML and JS for my page, and have problem with regular expression:

```
$replace = [    
...,
'~([\r\n\t ])?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)="([a-zA-Z0-9_/\\-]+)"([\r\n\t ])?~s' => '$1$2=$3'];

$scripts = preg_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $scripts);
$html = preg_replace($searchh, $replacee, $html);
```

But in case of expression like this:

```
    <script>var swatchImageOption4 = document.querySelector('div[data-option-id="4"]');
swatchImageOption4.style.background = "\u0023f70d0d no-repeat center";
swatchImageOption4.style.backgroundSize = "initial";</script>
```

It deletes **""** in **data-option-id="4"** and swatches on frontend doesnt work.
Any idea how can i change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by completly ignoring text between <script'> tags:

```
 '~([\r\n\t ])?(<script[^>]*>.*?</script>)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)="([a-zA-Z0-9_/\\-]+)"([\r\n\t ])?~s' => '${2:+$2:$3=$4}', //Conditional replace - if <script></script> ignore
```